# Calculate maneuver details from coordinates using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, map-directions

I want to calculate the maneuver details (turn-left, turn-right, etc) from the coordinates array returned by **google roads API**. I know maneuver details only returned by google directions API. But If I draw custom routes using roads API then how do I calculate maneuver details? I tried to calculate the degrees between two coordinates using this code:

```
function radians(n) {
  return n * (Math.PI / 180);
}
function degrees(n) {
  return n * (180 / Math.PI);
}

function getBearing(startLat,startLong,endLat,endLong){
  startLat = radians(startLat);
  startLong = radians(startLong);
  endLat = radians(endLat);
  endLong = radians(endLong);

  var dLong = endLong - startLong;

  var dPhi = Math.log(Math.tan(endLat/2.0+Math.PI/4.0)/Math.tan(startLat/2.0+Math.PI/4.0));
  if (Math.abs(dLong) > Math.PI){
    if (dLong > 0.0)
       dLong = -(2.0 * Math.PI - dLong);
    else
       dLong = (2.0 * Math.PI + dLong);
  }

  return (degrees(Math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0;
}
```

this function returns degrees, but I don't know how to calculate or what is the logic to manipulate the maneuver details from the degrees?

Is there any other way to calculate maneuver details from coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in c#. First I calculated Slopes of Line Joining two points. 2nd Colum of Datatable "create Path" was X amd 3rd Column was Y

```
    /// <Find Slopes>
    /// Find Slopes Between 2 Nodes:Value of Slope in radians
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List <double> slope(DataTable createPath)
    {
        List<double> slopes = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 1; i < createPath.Rows.Count; i++)
        {      
            slopes.Add (Math.Atan2((Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][2]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][2])),
                (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][1]) - Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i - 1][1]))));      
        }
        return slopes;
    }
```

once you get slopes

```
    /// <Directions: Turns Left or Right.>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="createPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<string> manoeuvre(DataTable createPath)
    {
        List<string> theManoeuvre = new List<string>();
        List<double> slopes = new List<double>();
        slopes = slope(createPath);
        int count = (slopes.Count);
        //Checking For Starights
        for (int i=1; i<count; i++)
        {
            if ((slopes[i]-slopes[i-1]) == 0)// Staright Combination
            {
                if (slopes[i-1] ==0)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Right");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == Math.PI)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Left");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == (Math.PI)/2)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Up");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == -(Math.PI)/2)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Down");
                else
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Slant");
            }
            else if ((((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) > 0) && ((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) <= Math.PI)) ||
                (((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) < (-1 * Math.PI)) && ((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) > (-2 * Math.PI))))
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][5]) != Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i+1][5]))

                    theManoeuvre.Add("Turn Left");
                else
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Lane Change");

            }
            else
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i][5]) != Convert.ToDouble(createPath.Rows[i + 1][5]))

                    theManoeuvre.Add("Turn Right");
                else
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Lane Change"); 
            }
        }
        return theManoeuvre;
    }
```

I hope it helps you. just to find the conditions.

Comment: When there is a straight Line between 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). then the Slope = arctan ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)). This is a very commanly used term in geometry. To find maneuver you need to compare two such straight lines. (ie. 3 points now.) if three points are in line then you are going staright. if not then you make some turn. Depending on Change of slopes of those 2 lines you calculate left or right.

Comment: I am trying. I will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Please tell me what value exists in `createPath.Rows[i][5]` ?

Comment: I am going to give you another answer if you don't need lane change.

Comment: Ok, It will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another answer without i+5,

```
    public List<string> manoeuvre(DataTable createPath)
    {
        List<string> theManoeuvre = new List<string>();
        List<double> slopes = new List<double>();
        slopes = slope(createPath);
        int count = (slopes.Count);
        //Checking For Starights
        for (int i=1; i<count; i++)
        {
            if ((slopes[i]-slopes[i-1]) == 0)// Staright Combination
            {
                if (slopes[i-1] ==0)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Right");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == Math.PI)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Left");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == (Math.PI)/2)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Up");
                else if (slopes[i-1] == -(Math.PI)/2)
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Straight Down");
                else
                    theManoeuvre.Add("Slant");
            }
            else if ((((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) > 0) && ((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) <= Math.PI)) ||
                (((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) < (-1 * Math.PI)) && ((slopes[i] - slopes[i - 1]) > (-2 * Math.PI))))
            {
                theManoeuvre.Add("Turn Left");
            }
            else
                theManoeuvre.Add("Turn Right");
        }
        return theManoeuvre;
    }
```

I us sixth column for putting the supposed Orientation of a Vehicle at that point to determine if its going be a lane change or just a right turn. I dont think you need it.